# Cmake throws "BUILD PYTHON" error during configuring when building openpose library

Tags: python, macos, cmake, openpose

I am very new to cmake and I am using Cmake Gui for compiling the openpose library https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose.
I am trying this on a mac machine.

Now, in the Cmake-GUI:

1. With the BUILD PYTHON flag set to OFF. The Configuration n
   Generation works!!
2. But, with BUILD PYTHON flag set to ON. The Configuration throws some
   errors[Posted below], though generation can be done too, but
   eventually the compilation throws an error of python.

I need this Python API to be used. Any help would be appreciated!

I am guessing there is something wrong with the pybind11.
Have tried removing the **pybind11** folder and did a `git clone` of pybind11; `git init` done.

```
Building CPU Only.
Found gflags  (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.dylib)
Found glog    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libglog.dylib)
Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) 
Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) 
Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) 
${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS} set by the user to /usr/local/include/caffe
${Caffe_LIBS} set by the user to /usr/local/lib/libcaffe.dylib
Download the models.
Downloading BODY_25 model...
Model already exists.
Downloading body (COCO) model...
Model already exists.
Downloading body (MPI) model...
Model already exists.
Downloading face model...
Model already exists.
Downloading hand model...
Model already exists.
Models Downloaded.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

pybind11 v2.3.dev0
Configuring done
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the code you are trying to run; did you ask its maintainer?

Comment: "but eventually the compilation throws an error of python." - Show that error (add it to the question post). The message "Configuring done" means that project is ready to be built, so the project doesn't treat previous messages as a problem.